# Comparing if any values of list one is greater than any value in another?

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [39, 4, 6]
list2 = [0, 7, 6]
[x for x in list2 if x < any(list1)]
```

Wanted results: 0, 7, 6 (since all < 39)
Actual result: 0

Edit: if

```
list2 = [0, 3, 6]
```

I would want to return 3 as 3 is < 7

Comment: Why don't you replace `any` with `max`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posted the solution yourself. You want all items lower than the **max** of the other list:

```py
list1 = [39, 4, 6]
list2 = [0, 7, 6]
[x for x in list2 if x < max(list1)]
```

Comment: This was an oversimplification of a problem I was solving for work, but you just gave me an epiphany for my ultimate goal. Thanks! Will accept your answer when the time limit elapses

Answer (score 0):

Python's 'any()' returns boolean, see [documentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any). So here, as it returns true, any(list1) becomes 1, so the loop takes form of:

```
[x for x in list2 if x < 1]
```

Which results in [0] (Only 0 is smaller than 1).

Answer (score 0):

If its meant to solve it using logical operators, try this:

```
list1 = [39, 4, 6]
list2 = [0, 7, 6]

a = [x for x in list2 if all(x<y for y in list1)]
```

result: `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

simply compare the max of each list and return the list with the lowest max

```
 def comparelist(l1, l2):
        if max(l1)> max(l2):
            return l2
        else:
            return l1
 print(comparelist(list_1, list_2))
```